# What is a good method for drawing a Möbius band on the blackboard?

Tags: undergraduate-education, topology, board-use

This week I'm going to give a talk on fiber bundles, and I found myself with an unexpected problem. Since I'm not using slides, I'll need to draw a Möbius band on the blackboard. Usually what I do is simply draw a rectangle with some arrows to indicate the identification, but I think I could do better.

Is there a method that can help me to draw a good Möbius band on the blackboard? I'm looking for something that looks good and is easy to draw.

Comment: I would show one made of paper, and I would practice drawing from good images online.

Comment: If fact, it is so easy to make paper ones everyone in the class should be encouraged to make a copy.

Comment: By talk do you mean a class you are teaching, or a research seminar, or something else? Paper ones will not be entirely appropriate in some contexts.

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch Very good idea! In my class we actually made our copies, and that was in high school. As a very beautiful and meaningful mathematical concept I wear a Möbius strip as my wedding ring, but as an object it is unfortunately too small for demonstration in front from a whole class.

Comment: Also look at: http://www.davidparker.com/janine/mathpage/topology.html#MOBIUS

Comment: One possibility for males (and some females), but proceed with extreme care and probably not something possible in many teaching environments today, is to take your belt off and demonstrate using your belt. I've never done this in a class, and probably never would, but I did do this a few months ago to show my wife what a Möbius band is. *(moments later)* I just now recalled something I did do in a class of gifted high school students. I took a sheet of paper, and folding it against the edge of the front (teacher) desk, I tore off a strip 5-8 cm wide and used that, and students did the same.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Draw the bottom three-quarters of an oval:
[image: mobius step 1]

Flesh that out to make the bottom half of the strip:
[image: mobius step 2]

Connect one of the open ends at the top to the bottom on the other side:
[image: mobius step 3]

Now draw a straight line across the top:
[image: mobius step 4]

Finally fill in the last edge at the back:
[image: mobius step 5]

An advantage to this approach is that it highlights the fact that the mobius strip starts out as an ordinary strip, but has a twist in one spot.

Note I figured out these steps by making various physical mobius strips with very thin width relative to their length, and manipulating them so that they were as loop-like as possible. One of the key features is the straight line at the top. That is due to how a curve in paper looks from the side -- same as at the sides of the picture.

Finally, I echo everyone else's sentiments: you should bring strips of paper so that everyone can make a real physical mobius strip of their own. There's nothing like seeing the physical real object to support the imagination!

Comment: I was wondering something similar, but I also thought it might be too broad. This question http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/what-is-an-efficient-way-of-drawing-surfaces-in-multivariable-calculus was on a similar theme, but didn't have a "how can I actually do it by hand" answer (yet)

Comment: I'm using yours. It's amazing.

Comment: @Newman  If you are using this one, you might want to accept his answer by clicking the checkmark at the upper lefthand corner of the post.

Comment: Very nice answer. I like these sorts of methods because this sort of thing does not come natural to me. I was going to comment (tongue-in-cheek) that one could first start by drawing a projective plane, and then follow by removing a disc to get a Mobius band.

Comment: +1 nice drawing. Great advice to bring paper and tape. To add to that - have some students cut the strip down the middle, others, 1/3 over. Interesting results.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I've put an answer to that other question on quadric surfaces, if you're interested http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/what-is-an-efficient-way-of-drawing-surfaces-in-multivariable-calculus

Comment: UPDATE: I used this drawing in my talk. It went great. This drawing is specially good to show that there isn't a natural homeomorphism between the fibers and the typical fiber, but two such homeomorphisms , and they are related by "reflect in the midpoint".

Answer (score 12):

I searched google images and found many nice renditions.
Here one that you may prefer from this [link](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rlg/images/mathforkidsimages/moebiusstrip.jpg)

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [umich.edu](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rlg/images/mathforkidsimages/moebiusstrip.jpg))</sub>  .

I especially like that it shows the width of the paper and doesn't draw the strip as a line or piece of string.
Having the students make them is always a hit.

Comment: I really like this one--per chance are there other figures you draw nicely?

Comment: @Addem  I wish I could draw anything. I got this from a link as explained in the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 8):

Since I use Seifert's algorithm to construct surfaces a lot, I tend to go for the flat approach:

[image: flat Mobius band]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of drawing on the blackboard, use a 3D model and pass it around when you're finished using it for demonstration.

If the class is small enough, you can bring in a strip of paper for each student to make his/her own.

The demonstration will be much more powerful this way and the lesson more likely to stick.

Comment: This allows people to actually vote up this particular answer as an independent idea instead of just always having it in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

A Möbius band can be constructed by cutting a cylinder and then rejoining its ends after a twist. So draw it the same way.

Draw a cylinder. This should be easy enough to do. Cut it by rubbing out parts of it. And then link it back with a twist.

This is in the same spirit as David's answer, with the added benefit that your audience can follow its construction with their imagination.

However, the use of blackboard may present a problem, as erasing tends to make an area less readable. Perhaps a different colour for the twist would help.