# Sketching paraboloids on paper

Tags: reference-request, concept-motivation, geometry, graduate-education, teacher-preparation

I have to teach sketching paraboloids on paper by looking at it's equation. Last year when I taught this topic no one was interested in learning this particular thing. They felt the topic difficult and utter waste of time with so much hard work to do. I know that at first it's difficult to visualize this topic and it becomes a pain to sketch them on paper. But I think it really develops an analytic approach towards coordinate geometry and mathematics in general.

How do I motivate students to take it seriously?
Which online source can I refer to supplement my knowledge about this particular topic?

I don't want to repeat what happened last year.

Comment: To what end are you teaching them sketching 3 dimensional objects?

Comment: @Adam I have taught them tracing of conicoids now I want to teach them sketching. For example, sketch the sections of the following conicoids by the planes given alongside. 1. $2y^2 + z^2 = 4$ , the plane $x = y$

Comment: not a duplicate but definitely related and might be helpful http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/constructing-and-sketching-parabolas-conic-sections-and-other-curves

Comment: @celeriko relieved to some extent because other profs. also face similar problem while teaching these topics in their clas.

Comment: @celeriko however it doesn't help much because it's more focused on parabola while my concern is regarding paraboloid.

Comment: @user109256 oops yeah sorry i now realize i misread your question, well maybe you can use some of those 2D sketching techniques to help motivate the 3D sketches? just spitballing here

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking but I think convincing students that you can solve 3-d problems (sketching a paraboloid) by solving analogous 2-d problems (level surfaces and other slices) is pretty good motivation.

Comment: Couldn't you get the same analysis using a computer system to graph everything?  You may have to ask slightly different types of questions, but it takes all the graphing part (which is a time-consuming part that is really hard to do on 2D paper) and frees up students to talk about the points that exist on the curve (or intersections, or whatever else you want).

Comment: When I learned calc III, I had a professor who was uniquely charismatic. The one line of his that really stuck with me was that all of the greatest artists "knew" calculus, because they understood space. (In hindsight it's probably safer to say analytic geometry, but that's not as sexy!) I thought it was a pretty cool thing to say. This was specifically in reference to drawing quadric surfaces.